# Loading Two List Items in One CSS Place (Top Position)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load two `<li>`s list in one place (same CSS position) at [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gkTq5/1/) I am not sure the jQuery which I am using is the best method to do this but it is working for me , so far.
The only issue is loading two list in two diffident positions. Here is the code I have:

```
(function() {
   var lis1 = $('.listOne li').hide();
   var lis2 = $('.listTwo li').hide(); 
   $('.disone').click(function() {
        var i = 0;
       (function displayList() {
        $('.listTwo li').hide();
         lis1.eq(i++).fadeIn(400, displayList);
      })();
   }); 
     $('.distwo').click(function() {
           $('.listOne li').hide();
        var i = 0;
       (function displayList() {

         lis2.eq(i++).fadeIn(400, displayList);
      })();
   });    

})();
```

Can you please let me know how to fix it in a way that both list populated in exact top position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with your CSS, not your javascript. `ul` elements by default have a `margin-bottom:10px`. Thus, the second is 10px below where you want it. To fix it simply add the following to your CSS

```
ul { margin-bottom:0; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkTq5/5/)

The best way to catch errors like this in positioning is to user your browser's inspect element to search for the added space

On a side note some of you list elements are not hidden if you click on th other list while it is fading in. Changing `.hide()` to `.hide(true, true)` fixes some of that isue

Comment: Thanks Zach, your hints also was very helpful.